# Instantiate abstract class workaround

Tags: java, graph, abstract

So since I will use various types of graphs I decided to put common behavior in abstract classes:

```
public abstract class Graph {

private List<Node> nodes;
private List<Edge> edges;

public void addNode(Node n) {
    nodes.add(n);
}

public void addEdge(Edge e) {
    edges.add(e);
}

public Node getNode(Node n) {
    return nodes.get(nodes.indexOf(n));
}

public Edge getEdge(Node left, Node right) {
    return edges.get(edges.indexOf(new Edge(left, right)));
   }
}
```

The `getNode()` does not complain (yet) even though the `Node` class is abstract. The problem is that the Edges are abstract too, but where the `equals()` and `hashCode()` has been overridden so that an edge can be identified by its nodes. It seems unnecessary to make the edge list protected or something else and implement the same `getEdge()` method in every subclass.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I don't understand, why would you have to "implement the same getEdge() method in every subclass" under any circumstances?

Comment: Because I want the get an edge from the edge list and call methods. E.g. I would have to call an getWeightedEdge(MaxFlowGraphNode n1, MaxFlowGraphNode n2) written in an MaxFlowGraph that extends Graph in order to change the weight on the edge.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Missed that. Thanks. Deleted the comment.

Comment: @bmorris591 OP would be forced to do that if he wants to keep his line `edges.get(edges.indexOf(new Edge(left, right))` because he can't instantiate the abstract `Edge` class. So he would have almost the same line repeated everywhere, just with a different `new xxxEdge` part.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I get ya. Well then move the repeated bit into an `abstract` method, i.e. have a factory method for `Edge`.

Comment: @bmorris591 I had that idea too (already had it written in an answer), but didn't like it since it doesn't look clean to me: the exact instance created is out of control; it may happen to be a particularly heavy `Edge` implementation, and it's not parsimonious to do that if all you need is comparing the connected nodes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik ah, fair point. A `Map` it is then...

Comment: @bmorris591 Maintaining such a `Map` could be a lot of work, cause thread-safety issues, etc., but for larger graphs it would still be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't make the `Edge` class abstract. If you have methods that you want implemented only in subclasses, make stub implementations in `Edge` that throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. In practice this causes very little actual problems because such errors in implementation are caught very early.

Another choice would be not to rely on `List#indexOf` but build your own custom algorithm that locates the edge based not on `equals` but on explicit comparison of the node pair. Basically it amounts to an implementation of `equals` semantics via an outside method (it could be a static method in `Edge` for convenience).

Comment: So it seems to work by changing to

    public Edge getEdge(Edge e) {
    return edges.get(edges.indexOf(e));
}

and calling the method with subclassed edges, e.g.

Edge maxFlowEdge = maxFlowGraph.getEdge(new maxFlowEdge(n1, n2))

Comment: If that doesn't result in code duplication for you, why not :)